# How to write a Search query in POSTGRES to return all rows which contain the user's searched word in their email

Tags: sql, database, postgresql

I am trying to implement a search function in my DRF project for that I have to write a query which returns all the nearby labs which contain the word entered by user in their email.
for example if user enters "S" in its search all labs containing the word S should be returned

This is what I wrote

```
SELECT *
,  ( 3596 * acos( cos( radians(33.6379647) ) 
* cos( radians( latitude ) ) * cos( radians( longitude ) - radians(73.1467503) ) +  sin( radians(33.6379647)
) * sin( radians( latitude ) ) ) ) AS distance 
FROM "Profiling_lab" 
WHERE (6371 * acos( cos( radians(33.6379647) ) * cos( radians(latitude) ) * cos( radians(longitude) - radians(73.1467503) ) + sin( radians(33.6379647) ) * sin( radians(latitude) ) ) )  <= 30 AND user_id LIKE 'Nis'  
ORDER BY distance
```

The issue is that it only returns labs where user_id(which contains the email) matches with user search 'Nis'(for example) matches word to word with the user_id

If my lab's email is nishat@email.com it will not be returned by sending 'Nis' in query.

This is my backend code in Django Rest Framework from where I am sending the query

```
@api_view(['POST'])
def NEARBYLABSAFTERQUERY(request):
    global my_long, my_lat
    my_long = str(request.data['longitude'])
    my_lat = str(request.data['latitude'])
    query = request.query_params.get('query')

    print(query)
    if request.data['Patient_id'] != "" and query != "":
        print("creating search history")
        Search = SearchHistory.objects.create(
            Search=query, Patient_id_id=request.data['Patient_id'], type="Lab")
        Search.save()

    if query == None:
        print("query is none")
        query = ""


    #Postgres query to select all labs within 30km radius and having user query in their name 
    labs = Lab.objects.raw('SELECT *,  ( 3596 * acos( cos( radians('+my_lat+') ) * cos( radians( latitude ) ) * cos( radians( longitude ) - radians('+my_long+') ) +  sin( radians('+my_lat+')) * sin( radians( latitude ) ) ) ) AS distance FROM "Profiling_lab" WHERE (6371 * acos( cos( radians('+my_lat+') ) * cos( radians(latitude) ) * cos( radians(longitude) - radians('+my_long+') ) + sin( radians('+my_lat+') ) * sin( radians(latitude) ) ) )  <= 30 AND user_id LIKE \''+query+'\'  ORDER BY distance')
    labSerializer = LabSerializer(labs, many=True)
    return Response(labSerializer.data)
```

Please help me to fix this issue

Comment: LIKE seems like the right tool for the job, you just need to add wildcards to the search string.  Why do you want to do something other than use the right tool?

Comment: its not  doing the job that I wanted it to do,  I think the issue is with the way I am writing the query. Someone pointed out that I am supposed to use %query%

Answer (score 0):

You would need to use LIKE with % operator, so in your case you can use either of the following:

`user_id LIKE '%nis%'` which will return anything that has nis in it.

`user_id LIKE 'nis%'` which will return anything starting with nis.

You can also read more about LIKE OPERATOR on here https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_like.asp

Comment: so if I am sending my backend query like user_id LIKE  \' '+query+ \'  I have to send it like \'%query% \' ?

Comment: I have tried sending '%query%' but it gives me TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting error